# esp32 on matlab

Tags: iota

Since nodemcu esp32 is not listed in the arduino package board, how do I configure the board for arduino set up and configuration?

Also, is the only way to send data to matlab through wifi is by using the thingspeak?

Comment: It would be better to ask two separate questions